# How to run a dynamic linear regression in R?

Tags: r, state-space, dlm

I am new to using R as I usually use Stata. I want to estimate a state space model on some time series data with time varying coefficients. From what I have gathered this is not possible to do in Stata.

I have downloaded the dlm package in R and I am trying to run the dlmModReg command to regress my dependent variable on a single explanatory variable. I would like to allow the intercept and beta coefficient to vary over time.

If anyone could show me an example of the code I want to run I think that would be enough for me to work out how to do this. The examples I have found online are vague or use terminology that I am not familiar with as a new R user. Any help or comments are greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are no help files in that package?

Comment: I have read what I assume are the help files. I am struggling to understand them because the examples are very vague. I'd really like to see an example of the code that uses data to estimate the model

Comment: Have you looked at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28961570/efficient-way-of-running-a-multivariate-linear-state-space-model-across-a-large

Comment: Thanks for that. It was still a bit above my level of understanding. I just found this: http://lalas.github.io/quantitativeThoughts/r/2014/09/01/dlmTutorial.html, which explains things i a simple enough way that I can follow.